# Get Filename from Remote machine directory using WMI

Tags: c#

I want to get The name of a fle which lies in remote machines C\Windows\Name directory using WMI .or count the number of files in remote  machine C\Windows\Name Directory using WMI.

Regards,
M.Channabasappa

Answer (score -1):

Do you have to use WMI, could you just do something like this?

```
    var machines = new List<String>;
    machines.Add("pc1");
    machines.Add("pc1");

    foreach (var machine in machines)
    {
    var dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(string.Format("\\{0}\Windows\",machine));                
        foreach (var path in dir.GetDirectories)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(path);
        }
   }
```

Comment: Yes i need to use WMI as our frmaework works on that .thanks for your suggestion